# What is fastest in reading data: dict, array np-array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I created three versions to store, but more important to read data in python3:

1. 1st: a dict with 970200 key - value pairs
2. 2nd: an 3-D np-array with dimension 100 and the same 907200 entries
3. 3rd: an array same as the np-array

Reading times for 500.000 reading operations are as followed:
(for testing I read 500.000 times the same value, entry)

1. 1st: 0..07379
2. 2nd:  0.3007
3. 3rd:  0.0987

I expected the np-array could be the fastest, but surprisingly it`s the slowest.

More details:
The 3d array could be seen as 3-D coordinates of points - nearly each point has a value assigned. This value is between [0, 3200]. In the 3-D array the 3 dimension are the position of the point, the entry is the value `a[222][333][444]=1111`.

Access-Version from  Tadhg McDonald-Jensen (a[222, 333, 444] for the np-array) takes: 0.129

The dict has key-value pairs like `"[222, 333, 444]":1111`
After creating these structures:
Assigning a value from the dict, the array or the np-array to a variable for 500.000 times results in above running times.

Update:
The data gets read from a file into the structure - in the program I want to access individual values from the structure (dict, np-array or array) in the memory. I`m timing the access in the memory only (after structure is already filled with data)

**Question:
Could my results be correct from a theoretical point of view - could an np-array be the slowest option to read data?**
Thank you for your help! ATramp

Comment: There is no question in this question... What do you need if you already tested your code and you know the fastes?

Comment: Update: Question added

Comment: Please add more details for your experiments

Comment: 'read the data' - from a file, or accessing individual values from the structure in memory?

Comment: *"Could my results be correct..."*  Without seeing the actual code, who knows?  Include the code, so anyone else can also run your test and try to reproduce the results.

Comment: np arrays are meant to be indexed by `a[222,333,444]` if you do it seperately `a[222][333][444]` you end up creating new series / slices of the original data for the intermidiate steps, that is why it is slowest, try indexing it the same way as the dict (the way it was meant to work) and see if you still get the same results.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your tip accelerated processing. Now it takes 0.129 seconds, approximately 1/3. But it is the slowest nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy is fast for numerical calculations on (large) arrays. You are measuring the access time for one element from Python code. Take this example:

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
a = np.arange(n)
d = dict.fromkeys(range(n))
```

The access to the dictionary is faster:

```
%timeit d[0]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 85.4 ns per loop
```

than the one to the NumPy array:

```
%timeit a[0]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 177 ns per loop
```

Note this time is independent form the size of the structure.

Conclusion: NumPy is fast for vectorized operations on arrays. Doing a lot of pure Python operations on NumPy arrays can be slower than staying with built-in Python datatypes.

> Question: Could my results be correct from a theoretical point of view
>   - could an np-array be the slowest option to read data?

Yes, this possible when accessing data in NumPy arrays from Python code is all you do with these arrays.

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem.